# Mounting new shocks/struts for 2002 Ford Focus SE

Tags: ford, suspension, focus, shock-absorber, struts

I am replacing the shocks/struts on my 2002 Ford Focus SE wagon. I have never done this before and am not using OEM parts - I'm using [this Moog strut assembly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CHFMZYU) - so I wanted to make sure I'm doing this right.

It looks slightly different than the original after install, protruding slightly below steering knuckle, and I'm wondering if this is ok, or if it needs to be perfectly flush and level? (See photo)

Also, what is the proper torque for the 3 mounting bolts up top, and for the one that clamps the steering knuckle to the bottom of the strut?

Thanks!

[Photo of new strut protruding from steering knuckle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSROx.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pinch bolt is 90Nm and the upper strut mount nuts are 25Nm.

As long as the strut isn't hitting the CV shaft it should be fine.